# What is an asymptotically nonnegative function?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I was reading up on the definition of theta- notation and came across this,

> The definition of $\Theta(g(n))$ requires that every member $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$  be
>   asymptotically nonnegative, that is, that $f(n)$ be nonnegative whenever $n$ is sufficiently large.

I'm having a little difficulty understanding what this means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there is some positive $N$ such that for all $n > N$, we have $f(n) \geq 0$.

Comment: Is it n > N  or n >= N. I see the latter over here https://www.quora.com/What-does-asymptotically-nonnegative-mean

Comment: It doesn't matter in any way: the two are entirely equivalent.